# Position sticky and gap in scrollable section

Tags: css, user-interface, frontend, position, sticky

Within the scrollable section i.e page_body class I want the "Position Sticky Section" to be fixed. I am using position: sticky; with top set to 10px to maintain gap on top. But I am facing issue on scroll with the gap of 10px created on top showing the scrollable content.

I want to maintain the design of the tbl_wrapper section even on scroll.

```css
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ECF0F4;
    overflow: hidden;
}

        .main_content{
                overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ECF0F4;
    height: 100%;
        }

        .content_wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    height: 100%;
}

.page_header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page_body {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 64px;
}

.margin_wrapper {
    margin-top: 48px;
}

.tbl_wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%), 0px 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 24%);
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 0 150px;
}

.tbl_wrapper .tbl_action_panel {
    position: sticky;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: inherit;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="main_content">

    <div class="content_wrapper">
        <div class="page_header">

            <div class="level2_header">
                <div class="page_title">Page Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="page_body">
     
            <div class="margin_wrapper">
                <div class="tbl_wrapper">
                    <div class="fx_c fx_a_c tbl_action_panel">

                        <div class="right_section">
                            <labe>Position Sticky Section</labe>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                     <div>
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                     </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: try using top: 0px; for the .tbl_action_panel class in the css

Comment: I know top:0 will fix this, but my question is that the top gap should be there